# Android Get next batch of sms/mms

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I need to retrieve the next 20 messages from the db in Android. I am retrieving the first 20 messages using the following code below:

```
Uri provider = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + threadId);
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(provider, new String[]{"_id", "ct_t"}, null, null, 
"_id desc limit 20");
//then used the id to get the actual message
```

This is working fine. But I need to get the next 20 messages starting from the last thread id and below. I have tried to add the selection:

```
"_id < lastMessageId"
```

But this gives me a null cursor. Another solution that i have in mind is to use the same code above but increase the limit by 20, but that will return unnecessary rows of data. Anyone can help me with this? Thanks!

EDIT:
I found this in logs.

```
SQLiteException: (ambiguous column name: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, ct_t FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date * 1 AS normalized_date, _id, NULL AS ct_t FROM sms WHERE (_id < ? AND thread_id = 25 AND (type != 3)) UNION SELECT DISTINCT date * 1000 AS normalized_date, pdu._id, ct_t FROM pdu LEFT JOIN pending_msgs ON pdu._id = pending_msgs.msg_id WHERE (_id < ? AND thread_id = 25 AND msg_box != 3 AND (msg_box != 3 AND (m_type = 128 OR m_type = 132 OR m_type = 130))) UNION SELECT DISTINCT date * 1 AS normalized_date, _id, NULL AS ct_t FROM cellbroadcast WHERE (_id < ? AND thread_id = 25) ORDER BY _id desc limit 20) ORDER BY _id desc limit 20)
```

Is there any way that i can only add the where clause on sms table only?

Answer (score 0):

The cursor shouldn't be null as if the query doesn't return results, its size (cursor.getCount()) would be 0.

Be sure to use the selection and selectionArgs correctly that is - 
selection ==> "_id < ?" and 
selectionArgs ==> String[]{lastThreadId.toString()}

provided the lastThreadId is Integer or if its an int you can use String.valueOf(lastThreadId) to wrap it into a String.

Also, you can use "_id < " + lastThreadId.toString() as your selection statement with selectionArgs null.

Comment: I already tried that but still it returns null. I'm suspecting that the "_id" is not applicable in the where clause since it was left join to other tables?